# Alguien sabe como actualizar una contraseña en laravel 10?

Tags: laravel

Este es el método utilizado para actualizar la contraseña.

```
public function updatePassword(Request $request) {     
    $user = Auth::user(); 
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->new_password);
    DB::table('users')->where('id', $user->id)->update(['password' => $user->password]);    
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Contraseña actualizada exitosamente.');
}
```

Esto para el login

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request){ 
  $credentials = $request->getCredentials(); 

  if( !Auth::validate($credentials)){ 
    return redirect()->to('/login')->withErrors('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos'); 
  } 
  $user = Auth::getProvider()->retrieveByCredentials($credentials); 
  Auth::login($user); 
  return $this->authenticated($request, $user); 
}
```

El problema ocurre al actualizar la contraseña, la cual muestra el mensaje "Contraseña actualizada exitosamente" y efectivamente actualiza la contraseña, pero al intentar ingresar la contraseña es incorrecta.

Comment: Y el logín como lo tienes?

Comment: public function login(LoginRequest $request){
        $credentials = $request->getCredentials();

        if( !Auth::validate($credentials)){
            return redirect()->to('/login')->withErrors('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos');
        }

        $user = Auth::getProvider()->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);
        Auth::login($user);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $user);
    }

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código de tu modelo User? Recuerda que cuando se utiliza ->update() en tu modelo User debes tener agregado `protected $fillable = ["password"];

Comment: Puedes guiarte por como lo hacen laravel-breeze y laravel-jetstream

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar una contraseña, generalmente se pide una confirmación, o sea que el usuario la escriba de nuevo en otro input.
Por ejemplo, en un formulario html:

```
<div>
    <label for="new_password">Password</label>
    <input id="new_password" type="password" name="new_password" required>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="new_password_confirmation">Confirmar Password</label>
    <input id="new_password_confirmation" type="password" name="new_password_confirmation" required>
</div>
```

También que envíe la contraseña anterior, para añadir seguridad.

```
<div>
    <label for="current_password">Password Actual</label>
    <input id="current_password" type="password" name="current_password" required>
</div>
```

Y todos esos datos se validan antes de actualizar la base de datos. Ref: [rule confirmed](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-confirmed), [rule current_password](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-current-password)

```php
$request->validate([
    'new_password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    'current_password' => 'current_password',
]);
```

Aunque lo que tienes podría funcionar, en el update estás haciendo pasos de más. En la documentación de laravel hay un [ejemplo](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/hashing#hashing-passwords) de cómo actualizar la contraseña:

```php
/**
 * Update the password for the user.
 */
public function updatePassword(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    // Valida el request aquí...
 
    $request->user()->fill([
        'password' => Hash::make($request->new_password)
    ])->save();
 
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Contraseña actualizada exitosamente.');
}
```

Finalmente, también hay un ejemplo de cómo hacer un login: [Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users).
No sé si te haya funcionado alguna vez eso que tenes, pero fijate lo que dice en la doc del metodo attempt

> You should not hash the incoming request's password value, since the framework will automatically hash the value before comparing it to the hashed password in the database.

porque puede ser eso lo que te está fallando para hacer el login.

```php
/**
* Handle an authentication attempt.
*/
public function authenticate(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    // $credentials = $request->getCredentials(); // no sé que es eso o si te funcionaba. Lo dejo como está en la doc.
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'], // cambia email por el campo que estés usando para las credenciales
        'password' => ['required'],
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }

    return back()->withErrors([
        'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
    ])->onlyInput('email'); // cambia email por el campo que estés usando para las credenciales
}
```